# Do smooth projective maps to $\mathbb{P}^1$ in positive characteristic have sections?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In response to the affirmative answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185171/does-every-smooth-projective-morphism-to-mathbbcp1-admit-a-section) using symplectic methods, I am wondering if the equivalent statement holds in positive characteristic?

Explicitly, over an algebraically closed field $k$ of positive characteristic $p > 0$, does every smooth projective morphism $f : X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ admit a section?

If we do not require $k$ to be separably closed, the question becomes uninteresting because of examples such as $\mathbb{P}^1_{k'} \to \mathbb{P}^1_k$ for any finite separable $k'/k$.

My guess is there should exist an example with no section. My idea was to find a surface admitting a nontrivial elliptic fibration over $\mathbb{P}^1$ with smooth fibers. Do there exist such counterexamples?

Comment: I believe the symplectic proof of existence of holomorphic sections of a projective smooth morphism to $\mathbb{CP}^1$ also works if there is a single critical value.  Glue the $2$-sphere to an "opposite" $2$-sphere along the boundaries of little disks centered at the critical values, and form the fibration over this new $2$-sphere by glueing the original fibration to its "opposite" fibration over the boundary of the disks.  So one could ask about the positive characteristic case with a single critical value, but this fails since the fundamental group of $\mathbb{A}^1$ is nontrivial.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It was wrong.

<strike>I think such examples exist, take as $f:Y\rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ any family of supersingular abelian varieties over $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ which is non-constant but constant up-to isogeny (e.g. take the Moret-Bailly pencil of supersingular abelian surfaces).
You cannot have a non-constant morphism $\mathbb P^1\rightarrow Y$, since the group $Y(\overline{\mathbb F_p}(t))$ is torsion (since the family is isotrivial up to isogeny) and any non-constant morphism $\mathbb P^1\rightarrow Y$ would correspond to a non-torsion element in $Y(\overline{\mathbb F_p}(t))$.</strike>

Comment: If $Y \to \mathbf P^1$ is a family of abelian varieties, doesn't that mean it has a zero section?

Comment: I think you want a nontrivial torsor for the family.

Comment: Ops...of course you are right... I don't know what I was thinking about... Sorry!

Comment: I doubt that there are nontrivial torsors for the family, since P^1 is simply connected, so one has to find a different route